# PJSIP : Crash on pj_sockaddr_get_port when moving iOS app to background and then to foreground

Tags: ios, iphone, voip, pjsip

I have an iOS VOIP app using PJSIP v2.3.0.

After the iOS 11 release, I have been seeing a lot of instances of the crash below. I have fabric (crashlytics) integrated with my app and this is the backtrace of the thread that crashed.

```
Crashed: Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x186819348 __pthread_kill + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18692d354 pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 396
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x186788fd8 abort + 140
3  libsystem_c.dylib              0x18675cabc basename_r + 314
4  MyApp                          0x101a2ab58 pj_sockaddr_get_port + 10115892
5  MyApp                          0x101a24e28 udp_on_read_complete + 10092036
6  MyApp                          0x1019bba74 ioqueue_dispatch_read_event + 9661008
7  MyApp                          0x1019bd1f0 pj_ioqueue_poll + 9667020
8  MyApp                          0x101a08788 pjsip_endpt_handle_events2 + 9975652
9  MyApp                          0x1019df334 worker_thread + 9806608
10 MyApp                          0x1019cf274 thread_main + 9740880
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18692c32c _pthread_body + 308
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18692c1f8 _pthread_body + 310
13 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18692ac38 thread_start + 4
```

The thread crashes due to assertion on pj_sockaddr_get_port

```
PJ_ASSERT_RETURN(a->addr.sa_family == PJ_AF_INET ||
             a->addr.sa_family == PJ_AF_INET6, (pj_uint16_t)0xFFFF);
```

Note : PJ_ENABLE_EXTRA_CHECK is defined 0 for my app so PJ_ASSERT_RETURN is simply PJ_ASSERT here.

The PJSIP logs leading upto this crash tells something interesting. The app is backgrounded and it unregisters. When the app is brought to foreground after several minutes, it tries to register.

I see the following warning messages and at the same time crashlytics reported the crash mentioned above with the backtrace.

```
2017-09-28 21:00:11 TID=50691 [pjsua] Log Level-1 : 16:00:11.267     ioq_select  Error replacing socket: Invalid argument
2017-09-28 21:00:11 TID=50691 [pjsua] Log Level-1 : 16:00:11.267     udp0x10de7f3a0  Warning: pj_ioqueue_recvfrom: [err 120009] Bad file descriptor
2017-09-28 21:00:11 TID=50691 [pjsua] Log Level-1 : 16:00:11.267     udp0x10de7f3a0  Warning: pj_ioqueue_recvfrom: [err 120009] Bad file descriptor
.
.
.
2017-09-28 21:00:18 TID=50691 [pjsua] Log Level-1 : 16:00:15.256     udp0x10de7f3a0  Warning: pj_ioqueue_recvfrom: [err 120057] Socket is not connected
2017-09-28 21:00:18 TID=50691 [pjsua] Log Level-1 : 16:00:15.256     udp0x10de7f3a0  Warning: pj_ioqueue_recvfrom: [err 120057] Socket is not connected
2017-09-28 21:00:18 TID=50691 [pjsua] Log Level-1 : 16:00:15.256     udp0x10de7f3a0  Warning: pj_ioqueue_recvfrom: [err 120057] Socket is not connected
.
.
.
2017-09-28 21:00:18 TID=50691 [pjsua] Log Level-1 : 16:00:18.262 udp0x10de7f3a0  Warning: pj_ioqueue_recvfrom: [err 120038] Socket operation on non-socket
2017-09-28 21:00:18 TID=50691 [pjsua] Log Level-1 : 16:00:18.262 udp0x10de7f3a0  Warning: pj_ioqueue_recvfrom: [err 120038] Socket operation on non-socket
2017-09-28 21:00:18 TID=50691 [pjsua] Log Level-1 : 16:00:18.262 udp0x10de7f3a0  Warning: pj_ioqueue_recvfrom: [err 120038] Socket operation on non-socket
```

These warning messages appear because of spinning loop inside udp_on_read_complete from what I understand. Could iOS be re-claiming the socket that pjsip is trying to use?

Did anybody come across this crash? Any kind of pointers/guide is most welcome.

Comment: I have observed similar issue related to this. Did you have any success resolving this?

Comment: I have a workaround for this problem in pjsip which is under testing right now. I will update you with the fix once I get positive result. 
Thanks.

Comment: How you handle `applicationDidEnterBackground:` and `applicationWillEnterForeground:`? You need to provide your code.

Comment: Please take a look at the fix I gave in answer.

Comment: @adsun I'm using PJSIP for making outgoing calls and incoming calls in my app. When  I make call it works proper in some way. But some times I'm getting multiple incoming calls so I checked with support team and they responded that,
"Where you able to confirm that your application or system is responding with a 200 OK to our webhooks? otherwise we would consider it a failed attempt and continue to retry which might be the reason you got 3 exact webhooks.
The destination is not responding beyond 100 Trying prompting us to cancel the call due to timeout. Default is 5 seconds." what to do now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fix I made was to simply return from ioqueue_dispatch_read_event method in pjlib/src/pj/ioqueue_common_abs.c when the replace_udp_sock() fails. The crash was happening because the error was ignored and on_read_complete was called with bad socket.

Change I made:

```
rc = replace_udp_sock(h);
if (rc != PJ_SUCCESS) {
  PJ_LOG(3, (THIS_FILE, "UDP socket replacement failed with error status %d", rc));
  if (has_lock) {
      pj_ioqueue_unlock_key(h);
  }
  return;
}
```

Let me know if this solves the problem for you.

Comment: but ioqueue_dispatch_read_event function should return a bool value. Did you mean _return_ _PJ_FALSE;_ ??

Comment: I use PJSIP v2.3.0. The method is in file pjlib/src/pj/ioqueue_common_abs.c and has the signature: 
   
void ioqueue_dispatch_read_event( pj_ioqueue_t *ioqueue, pj_ioqueue_key_t *h )

Comment: Inv 2.7.1 it's pj_bool_t ioqueue_dispatch_read_event(pj_ioqueue_t *ioqueue, pj_ioqueue_key_t *h ). I think maybe put PJ_IPHONE_OS_HAS_MULTITASKING_SUPPORT to 0 for ignore the replace_udp_sock() block.

Comment: @adsun we are having a similar issue in production, and were hoping to pick your brain on some of your findings. It looks like we can't DM on StackOverflow... is there a better way to get a hold of you?

Comment: @GuillermoMoratorio you can use pjsua_destroy2(PJSUA_DESTROY_NO_RX_MSG); on exit to the background and register back on entrance to foreground. I try this way temporary

Comment: @GuillermoMoratorio If you are subscribed to PJSIP forum list, you can see that I sent an email with same exact content some time in October 2017. You can reach out to me via that email address. I'll see how I can help.

Comment: @adsun I'm also facing this assertion crash but it is facing on particular user having a connection with mobile data 4G and trying to register with pjsip. We're using pjsip-ios Pod for VOIP functionality. Can you please suggest why this faces on particular user having 4G network. and what is solution for this. It works when use wi-fi for registration. Getting crash only on 4G network.

Comment: @ParthBarot - The fix I made above has been formally included in later versions of PJSIP. I would highly recommend looking at the latest version of PJSIP for this specific method and how they are handling this scenario and update it if not already. I guess it is happening because OS could be trying to be more restrictive of resource usage when in mobile data mode.

Comment: @adsun Are you using this pod ?
https://github.com/chebur/pjsip
and if you are using another pod then please share here.

Comment: @ParthBarot No, we are not using this. We build PJSIP directly from the source for iOS and integrate it. 
https://github.com/pjsip/pjproject

Comment: @adsun That crash is solved now. Thanks for your suggestion. But I have another issue that, while we make call at that time some times we're not able to here ringing voice. And this issue comes randomly. We've checked with provider and they said that "Your IP is not responding with a 180 ringing within timeframe. For some reason Your system is not sending any ringback (SIP 180 message)". So could you suggest that how to reply to this with SIP 180 ringback.

Comment: @ParthBarot Not sure if that issue is related to this one. I would suggest creating a new question with all the relevant details and logs.